# Why is the "My account" link shown even if it is disabled?

Tags: navigation

In "Administration > Structure > Menu," I disabled the "My account" link, but the theme is still showing it.

[image: screenshot]

I took the screenshot after disabling the link, closing the overlay, and clicking the "reload" button of the browser; still the link is show, even if it is disabled.
Why is it happening?

If I disable the "Log out" link that doesn't appear anymore.

[image: screenshot]

Why is the "My account" link so special? More importantly, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could disable it by clicking "edit" and then unchecking the "enable" box.

Comment: I was disabling it from the page that I have shown in the screenshots, and it was not working. I didn't think of disabling it from the edit page; I took that the effect should have been the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug and is already discussed a lot:

http://drupal.org/node/1092866

http://drupal.org/node/1197622

Quick fix would be to create a new menu and add that in your template.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the menu item of the user profile was always marked as disabled in the settings. As administrator I could always see the menu item on the front end, other users could never see it. In [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71671/39742) I found a workaround with the module [menu_token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) and setting the path to `user/[current-user:uid]`.