# How can I add a direct link to the edit account settings page in a menu?

Tags: routes

Ok, I must be missing something obvious, but I'm having trouble adding a link to `user/%/edit` to the main menu.  In the Menu UI, I clicked "add link," set the title to "Account settings," and then was at a loss about what to put for the path.  I know how to generate a link to the account edit page using views, which is what I've always done before, but this time I actually need to add the link to the "Main Menu."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Drupal 8,9,10 etc.** you can do this by providing a custom route to point to `/user/edit` for example and have this route call a controller to perform a simple redirect. You can then simply link to `/user/edit` from anywhere you want and the redirect will bring the user to their correct `/user/%/edit` form.

The [User Current Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_current_paths) module does exactly that. Use this module or have a look a their approach, which can be extended easily to provide more complex dynamic redirects as well.

- The routing entry: [user_current_paths.routing.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/user_current_paths/-/blob/2.0.2/user_current_paths.routing.yml#L1-6)
- The callback: [src/Controller/UserCurrentPathsController.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/user_current_paths/-/blob/2.0.x/src/Controller/UserCurrentPathsController.php#L81-91)

Answer (score 11):

Try this module [menu_token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) , it allows to use tokens in menu

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly" to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).

Answer (score 5):

You can't use % as a wildcard when adding a menu item like that.

The [me aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module can help you do it.

You install that module and then you can add a menu item to user/me/edit and it will go to the currently logged in user's edit page.

Comment: The module smile mentions is a good option too.

Comment: The 'me' aliases module changed all of my user admin links so I can't edit user tabs anymore so I won't recommend it.

Comment: It's a valid solution that works for me. I don't see why it is worth a down vote as it is not a wrong answer. But whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Create a node with input format filter set as **PHP code** and copy/paste the following code:

```
<?php
drupal_goto('user/'.$GLOBALS['user']->uid.'/edit');
?>
```

Under menu settings, create a menu link and add it to a menu.

https://drupal.org/comment/4098302#comment-4098302

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but would probably work.